# Multiple REST calls - best practise

Tags: jquery, rest, asynchronous

i would like to do following:

1.Multiple call single REST service
2.Store all received data in array
3.When all data received, iterate throug array filter and display data.

I have following code (not exact copy, just pseudocode :))

```
for(var i = 0; i < numberOfRestCalls; i++){
   $.ajax(
      url: 'url'
      success: function(result){
         storeDataInArray();
      }
   )
}

for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
   if (array[j] == something)
      displayData(array[j]);
}
```

But sometimes happens, that not all data is loaded. It is probably because ajax is async, so second for cycle is iterated before all data is loaded.
So, how can i wait for all REST calls to complete?
ty for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take advantage of [`$.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) and [deferreds](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Deferred) for this. You don't know in what order the ajax calls are going to complete so the only time that you can act on all the results is when they all have completed. Something like the following *should* work

```
var ajaxCalls = [];

for(var i = 0; i < numberOfRestCalls; i++){
   ajaxCalls.push($.ajax({ url: 'url' }));
}

$.when.apply($, ajaxCalls).done(function() {

    // arguments here will be arrays for the ajax requests in
    // ajaxCalls, where each array looks like [ data , statusText, jqXHR ]
    var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);

    for(var i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
       storeDataInArray(args[0])
    }

    // do something with all results from storeDataInArray() function calls

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about ajax, one way could be to have storeDataInArray() function to print the data when all the callbacks have come. May be a counter(say COUNTER) count the number of calls to storeDataInArray(). When that COUNTER reaches numberOfRestCalls, we can put the for loop inside that to display all the data.

```
success: function(result){
   counter++;//declare this somewhere in global scope
   if(counter == numberOfRestCalls)
   {
      for (var j = 0; j < array.length; j++){
       if (array[j] == something)
         displayData(array[j]);
      }
   }
   else
   {
      //store the data in array[counter]
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.